# Resizing image in div with other elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div with an image and a variable amount of text that may make up 0, 1, or multiple lines. How can I get the image to resize so that both elements combined do not go over the height of the parent div?

In the example below, the image takes up the full height of the div (30vh) and the text div is below. I'd like the image to take up as much space as possible, so if there are 0 lines of text it will take up the full div, and only resize enough to allow the text to fit in the parent div.

```css
#test {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <img src="..."><br />
  <div>Variable amount of text</div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4, if that has any functions to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container (`.test` should be a flexbox column). Instead of img use a div with the image as the background and `flex: 1`.

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 50%;
}

.img {
  flex: 1;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/464/200/300) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div>Variable amount of text</div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div>Variable amount of text Variable amount of text Variable amount of text Variable amount of text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! However, "background-size: cover" cropped large images, so I used "background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;" to get it exactly as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
div#test img {
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: That won't make any difference at all.

Comment: you can try using the height equal to the div's height with `!important` property